# How to change order for :bnext and :bprevious in vim?

Tags: vim

In vim I'm opening 3 files in buffers: A,B,C (in this order). I'm going back to buffer B, I open buffer D (:e d) while being in B (so now I'm in D). But when I use :bprevious I go to C, but I would like to go to last visited buffer - B.

Is it possible to change buffer swiching order to use order of they activity, as in example above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to change the buffer list's order without some possibly dirty heavy lifting but there are quite a lot of [buffer navigation plugins](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Easier_buffer_switching#Scripts) available.

[This one](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2346), from the list, seems to adress your problem perfectly.

If you don't need to go to the previouser-previouser-previouser-previouser buffer, you might consider `<C-^>` to switch to the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the argument list. See `:help :args`. 
You can edit a file and put in the argument list easily with the `:argedit` command. The argument list behave exactly what you would like. 
You can use `:n` command to edit the next file in the argument list and `:N` (or `:prev`) to edit the previous. It's even shorter then `:bp` and `:bn` !

+1 for editing the alternate file as @romainl said. It's really fast !

Comment: `:help arglist` for an introduction to the argument list.